# How can I make a Django query for the first occurrence of a foreign key in a column?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

Basically, I have a table with a bunch of foreign keys and I'm trying to query only the first occurrence of a particular key by the "created" field. Using the Blog/Entry example, if the Entry model has a foreign key to Blog and a foreign key to User, then how can I construct a query to select all Entries in which a particular User has written the first one for the various Blogs?

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    ...

class User(models.Model):
    ...

class Entry(models.Model): 
    blog = models.Foreignkey(Blog)
    user = models.Foreignkey(User)
```

I assume there's some magic I'm missing to select the first entries of a blog and that I can simple filter further down to a particular user by appending:

```
query = Entry.objects.magicquery.filter(user=user)
```

But maybe there's some other more efficient way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`query = Entry.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('id')[0]`

Basically order by id (lowest to highest), and slice it to get only the first hit from the QuerySet.

I don't have a Django install available right now to test my line, so please check the documentation if somehow I have a type above:

[order by](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by-fields)

[limiting querysets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

By the way, interesting note on 'limiting queysets" manual section:

> To retrieve a single object rather
>   than a list (e.g. SELECT foo FROM bar
>   LIMIT 1), use a simple index instead
>   of a slice. For example, this returns
>   the first Entry in the database, after
>   ordering entries alphabetically by
>   headline:
>
> `Entry.objects.order_by('headline')[0]`

EDIT: Ok, this is the best I could come up so far (after yours and mine comment). It doesn't return Entry objects, but its ids as `entry_id`.

`query = Entry.objects.values('blog').filter(user=user).annotate(Count('blog')).annotate(entry_id=Min('id'))`

I'll keep looking for a better way.

Comment: I should have mentioned that a User can write for multiple Blogs. So the limit only shows the first Entry the user ever wrote. I want to be able to grab all entries that the user wrote which are the first entries for any blog.

Comment: I see, my answer doesn't work in this case, and I'm unable to have something working only with queryset methods... values() and annotate() don't work together as I'm expecting, and I can't translate the raw SQL that I know it'll work into Django's ORM. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Ancient question, I realise - @zalew's response is close but will likely result in the error:

> ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial
>   ORDER BY expressions

To correct this, try aligning the `ordering` and `distinct` parts of the query:

```
Entry.objects.filter(user=user).distinct("blog").order_by("blog", "created")
```

As a bonus, in case of multiple entries being created at exactly the same time (unlikely, but you never know!), you could add determinism by including `id` in the `order_by`:

To correct this, try aligning the `ordering` and `distinct` parts of the query:

```
Entry.objects.filter(user=user).distinct("blog").order_by("blog", "created", "id")
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't test it in this particular moment

```
Entry.objects.filter(user=user).distinct("blog").order_by("id")
```